# error: Error: Unable to resolve module @react-native-masked-view/masked-view

Tags: react-native

I have a bit of a complex problem I use in react native cli
I have the package
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
But shows me an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCqUJ.png)

Comment: Did you run `pod install` in `ios` directory after installing it?

Answer (score 0):

Please delete node modules,

then run these commands:

```
cd android
./graldew clean
cd ..
npm i
```